# Read double scientific notation with 'D' as exponent prefix in C++

Tags: c++, string, io

I am trying to read values that are written as `-0.49430978D-02`, but they are only coming in as `-0.49430978`. I have the characters saved in a string `vs` and have attempted both

`myval = stod(vs)`

as well as

`sscanf(vs.c_str(), "%le", &myval)`

but both of them fail to read the exponent in the scientific notation. Is it because it is `D` and not `E`? How do I read this value correctly in `c++`?

Comment: If the D can be replaced with an E (that's not clear, but if), why not just replace it before using regular C++ functionality like `stod`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `D` format is an uncommon floating point representation common to some Fortran implementations to indicate double precision (or greater).  AFAIK, all other environments use `E` for floating point and do not indicate the underlying precision.

I think your only choice is to read the value as a string, replace any `D` characters with `E` and then finish processing with `strtod()` or equivalent.